# how to send message from client to server socket

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i am trying to detect if usb connect to client side. what my logic is that to get the total number of disks if new disk added means new devices is added on client if usb remove from client means devices is remove from client so i keep checking in loop the client show total = 1 or total = 2 , 1 means only 1 disk is available 2 means new device is added and so on. It working fine but the `sock.send("Device Added in " + username) sock.send("Device remove in " + username)`  these command not working i dont get these message on server side if i plug or plug out the usb from client side. i am not sure if my `if else` conditions are correct or not.

os `linux`

this is client side code

```
from socket import *
import os, string, time
import getpass

host = 'localhost'  
port = 52000
username = getpass.getuser()

sock = socket()
# Connecting to socket
sock.connect((host, port))  # Connect takes tuple of host and port

def detect_device(previous):
    
    total = os.system(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l')
    time.sleep(3)
# if conditon if new device add
    if total<previous:
     sock.send("Device Added in " + username)
# if no new device add or remove
    elif total==previous:
     detect_device(previous)
# if device remove
    else:
     sock.send("Device Removed in " + username)
# Infinite loop to keep client running.
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if (data == 'Hi'):
        while True:
            detect_device(os.system(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l'))

sock.close()
```

output i get on client side is
`1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1`

1 means current number of total disks are 1 if i plug usb then total number of disks is 2 then 1 means i disconnect USB

Comment: Sockets read and write binary data. You are sending a string. You need to encode it, something like: `sock.send(f"Device Removed in {username}".encode("ascii"))`.

Comment: it say remove leading f

Comment: same what i find is that i get 0 in return when i run os command

Comment: You must be using Python3.5 or earlier, since the f-string syntax seems unsupported. So you can use `sock.send(("Device Removed in " + username).encode("ascii"))` instead. And `os.system` doesn't return the standard output of a command, it returns the command's exit code. So zero means it ran successfully. Subprocess is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fixed it out the os.system return 0 in output so i try it with subprocess.run and it runs fine.